# Day of the week between two other days

Tags: php, date

I got two dates stored with `date("w")` in PHP (day of the week, from 0 to 6), and I need to know if current day (again with w) is between those two.
Pretty easy, except for the sunday part. I can't just do something like

```
$now = date("w");
if ($first_day < $now < $sec_day){
    //is in between
}
```

cause if `$first_day = 5`, `$now = 6` and `$sec_day = 0`, this would fail even if it is in between.
How should I approach this ?

Comment: check one more condition before this condition `if($first_day != 5 && $now != 6)`

Comment: This was just an example. Other cases could fail.

Comment: put Other cases in else part

Answer (score 1):

Only need to alter the days in case the first day is bigger than the last day :

```
//first correct days
if ($first_day > $sec_day){
    if ($now > $first_day){
        $sec_day+=7;
    }
    if ($now < $first_day)
        $first_day-=7;
    }
}
if ($first_day < $now < $sec_day){
    //is in between
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. Saturday isn't found between Friday and Sunday, unless you're starting to speak of different weeks. In which case you need to take `date("W")` (week number) into account. A simple solution would be to use `date("z");` which means the day of the year. You cannot determine if a day is between two days without looking at the greater date.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I feel there must be a way to check if tuesday is coming after sunday and before wednesday no??

Comment: I need to do this check every week of the year recurringly, I do not have greater dates.

Comment: You must understand that it's possible that a Tuesday is found after Wednesday and before a Sunday as well. It all depends on the context you ask. If you're looking at the same week, use `date("N")` which gives 1-7 Monday-Sunday.

Comment: I see what you mean, but not in this case. Tuesday is not between wednesday and sunday, IF wednesday is declared as the first day and sunday the last one. Think about it as a timeline...